# Saving a dataframe results in Strings of Lists instead of Lists

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Assuming I have a column of a DF that has entries that look like this:

`df["column"] = [["this","is","a","tokenized","sentence","."],[...]]`

When I save the DF and read it in another file it looks like however:

`df2["column"] = "[["this","is","a","tokenized","sentence","."],[...]]"`

So if I now want to use the words (=strings) in the list I get:

`df2["column"][0] = [`

Instead of the desired:

`df2["column"][0] = [["this","is","a","tokenized","sentence","."],[...]]`

And further:

`df2["column"][0][0] = ["this","is","a","tokenized","sentence","."]`

---

I've tried using pd.eval, eval, literal_eval, various as_type operations but none of them return the desired result.

Comment: what format you are saving you data ?

Comment: for i, v in enumerate(dfs, 1):
    v.to_csv(fr'{directory}\df_split_{i}.csv', index=False)

.csv with the aforementioned method as the df is too large for a single file

Comment: could you try saving as pickle or parquet, load time will be much faster as well due to serialization

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your dataframe as csv, you have to use `converters` when you want to load your data:

```
>>> df
                                                         column
0  [[this, is, a, tokenized, sentence, .], [another, sentence]]

>>> df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

```
def string_as_list(s):
    return pd.eval(s)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'column': string_as_list})
print(df.loc[0, 'column'])
print(type(df.loc[0, 'column']))

# Output
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'tokenized', 'sentence', '.'], ['another', 'sentence']]
<class 'list'>
```